# C# Deserialize List<someobject> restfully with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm attempting to receive a POSTed List of POCO but I'm unable to deserialize either via the Swagger API or via Postman when submitting over the wire.  I've serialized the object back out to confirm how it supposed to be serialized, but when returning that back the body of the form, the request object parameter is null.

```
public class NameValuePair
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class NameValueList
{
    private List<NameValuePair> valuesToProcess = null;

    public List<NameValuePair> ValuesToProcess { get { return valuesToProcess; } set { valuesToProcess = value; } }

    public NameValueList()
    {
        valuesToProcess = new List<NameValuePair>();
    }
}

[Api("A description of what the API does")]
[Tag("Enriching Requests")]
[ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Your request was not understood")]
[ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Oops, something broke")]
[Route("/EnrichValueList", "POST", Summary = "Summary of the Web Get method", Notes = "Longer information about what this service does")]

public class EnrichValueList : IPost, IReturn<EnrichValueListResponse>
{

    [ApiMember(Name = "NameValues", Description = "A string that represents a value with which to understand more information about", ParameterType = "body", DataType = "NameValueList", IsRequired = true)]
    public NameValueList NameValues
    {
        get;

        set;
    }

    [ApiMember(Name = "AssociatedActivities", Description = "A comma seperated string that links Enrichment Activities with this value", ParameterType = "body", DataType = "string", IsRequired = false)]
    public string AssociatedActivities
    {
        get;

        set;
    }

}
```

The request.NameValues in this case is null (no error is thrown):

```
public async Task<EnrichValueListResponse> Post(EnrichValueList request)
    {
        EnrichValueListResponse enrichValueListResponse = new EnrichValueListResponse();

        return enrichValueListResponse;
    }
```

I've already got other methods that receive a string of stringyfied object and then use the JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString method from ServiceStack.Text so completely fine with that approach. I was attempting to use a more strongly typed object in the original request (which may not be possible or I'm doing it wrong).

Param: NameValues, Value {"valuesToProcess":[{"name":"bob","value":"Not Bob"}]}

and trying about every other permutation I can think of.  Interestingly, when changing to plain string parameters and posting, the inbuilt swagger API returns a deserialization error, but Postman is fine.

**Swagger Top Half**
[image: Swagger 1]

**Swagger Bottom Half**
[image: Swagger 2]

Response Body as text

```
{
  "responseStatus": {
    "errorCode": "SerializationException",
    "message": "Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'EnrichValueList', got string starting with: \"two\"",
    "stackTrace": "   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJson.StringToType(ReadOnlySpan`1 strType, TypeConfig typeConfig, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, KeyValuePair`2[] typeAccessors)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeType`1.StringToTypeContext.DeserializeJson(ReadOnlySpan`1 value)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonReader.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<GetParseSpanFn>b__0(ReadOnlySpan`1 v)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromSpan(Type type, ReadOnlySpan`1 value)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Memory.NetCoreMemory.Deserialize(MemoryStream memoryStream, Boolean fromPool, Type type, DeserializeStringSpanDelegate deserializer)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Memory.NetCoreMemory.DeserializeAsync(Stream stream, Type type, DeserializeStringSpanDelegate deserializer)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequestAsync(IRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath, Dictionary`2 requestParams)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequestAsync(IRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest req, IResponse httpRes, String operationName)"
  }
}
```

**Postman**
[image: Postman 1]

***Update***

Following [@mythz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85785/mythz) advice, I removed both the ParameterType and the DataType from the decorator and I was able to exhibit some slightly different behaviour.

Using the example classes:

```
public class NameValues
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }

    public NameValues()
    {
        Values = new List<string>();
        Name = string.Empty;
    }
}

public class NameValuesList
{

    public List<NameValues> ValuesToProcess { get; set; }

    public NameValuesList()
    {
        ValuesToProcess = new List<NameValues>();
    }

}
```

and setting the DTO parameter to this

```
    [ApiMember(Name = "NameValues", Description = "A string that represents a value with which to understand more information about", IsRequired = true)]
    public NameValuesList NameValues
    {
        get;

        set;
    }
```

causes the same deserialization error when I pass in a JSON structure that should deserialize.  However, if I pass in some deformed string, it throws no error and just runs on through to the IPost handler method with a null for the property.

If I change the API parameter back to a string and use this example to show serialization and deserialization using the ServiceStack.Text library, works like a charm through both Swagger and Postman.

```
    public async Task<EnrichValueListResponse> Post(EnrichValueList request)
    {
        EnrichValueListResponse enrichValueListResponse = new EnrichValueListResponse();

        // Create a dummy object to serialize as JSON to return as an example back to the caller
        NameValuesList stuff = new NameValuesList();
        stuff.ValuesToProcess.Add(new NameValues { Name = "first", Values = { "second", "third" } });
        enrichValueListResponse.BatchId = await Task.Run(() => stuff.ToJson().IndentJson());

        // Deserialize the inbound string
        NameValuesList betterStuff = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<NameValuesList>(request.NameValues);

        return enrichValueListResponse;
    }
```

JSON submitted (although I did try many different variations of encoding and structure).

```
{
    "valuesToProcess": [
        {
            "name": "first",
            "values": [
                "second",
                "third"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've got debug mode set, but not seeing any exceptions thrown to the SeriLog db during parsing.  For now, I'll run with string parameter and derserialize after the fact.  I can do some pre-checking in the Fluent Validator

Comment: Done, thanks for the advice [@mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills)

Comment: Try not specifying the ParameterType or DataType on your properties.